# Viewing man pages in Vim

Tags: bash, vim, man, function

I wrote a function in Bash to see [man](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html) pages in Vim:

```
viman () { man "$@" | vim -R +":set ft=man" - ; }
```

This works fine, the only problem occurs if I pass a man page to it which doesn't exist. It prints that the man page doesn't exist but still opens `vim` with an empty buffer.
So, I changed the function to check the error code (which is `16` here) and exit if the page doesn't exist. The modified function looks somewhat like this:

```
viman () { man "$@" | [[ $? == 16 ]] && exit 1 | vim -R +":set ft=man" -  ; }
```

But, now it doesn't do anything.

**I just want to quit the program if the man page doesn't exist, otherwise open the man page with `vim`.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this: capture the man output, and if successful launch vim

```
viman () { text=$(man "$@") && echo "$text" | vim -R +":set ft=man" - ; }
```

Comment: Capturing the output in a text is a simple and brilliant idea. Putting all things together the `viman` function is ready - `viman () { text=$(man "$@") && echo "$text" | vim -R +":set ft=man nomod nonu noma nolist colorcolumn=" - ; }`

Answer (score 3):

I like the idea of checking the `man` return code; you can't pipe to the test, though. You could just run `man` twice:

```
viman () { man "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1 && man "$@" | vim -R +":set ft=man" - ; }
```

This runs `man ... | vim ...` only if the first invocation of `man` was successful.

Answer (score 2):

There's an environment variable called `MANPAGER` which can be used to make `man` call the command you want for displaying the manpage. The advantage of this is that you call `man` directly, and it won't run the pager at all if the manpage didn't exist.

So a wrapper script, say in `~/bin/vimman`:

```sh
#! /bin/sh
vim -R +":set ft=man" -
```

With this in your shell initialisation files somewhere:

```sh
export MANPAGER="$HOME/bin/vimman"
```

And you can directly run `man foo` to manpages in Vim.

(Depending on the `man` command being used, you could also have:

```sh
export MANPAGER='vim -R +":set ft=man" -'
```

directly instead of a wrapper script.)

---

If you have a new enough Vim, you can use the `--not-a-term` option to stop Vim from complaining about stdin not being a TTY.

---

Shameless plug: I wrote [a small plugin](https://github.com/muru/vim-manpager) to facilitate using Vim as manpager.

Comment: This is also a nice solution, but let me ask you, I depend a lot on manpage than on google or at least try to, so I've written different wrappers to make manpager interesting , for there is a gui manpager that works with yelp, now I am wondering if the yelp will be able to work with this?

Comment: @RitajitKundu if you're using yelp, you can directly open manpages in it: `yelp man:foo` (https://askubuntu.com/a/390095/158442)

Answer (score 2):

```bash
export MANPAGER='nvim +Man!'
```

Works for Bash and Zsh. Reports an error if the manual entry is not found, without opening Neovim.

See the [documentation](https://neovim.io/doc/user/filetype.html#ft-man-plugin) on how to use the `Man` plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13920/1866) this starts vim and exits if there's nothing in the buffer. The disadvantage is that it starts `vim` so the screen "flashes". It also doesn't set an exit code when a `man` page isn't found.

```
viman () { vim -R +':set ft=man|exe !search(".")?"quit!":""' <(man "$@" 2>/dev/null); }
```

This is an improvement on Jeff Schaller's answer in that it doesn't load the the `man` page twice when it exists. It also doesn't load `vim` unnecessarily like my previous example. And it *does* set an exit code when there's no `man` page.

```
viman () { man -f "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1 && vim -R +":set ft=man" <(man "$@"); }
```

Both examples use Bash process substitution in order to avoid the "Vim: Reading from stdin..." message.

Neither loads the page into a variable.

Comment: An even more lightweight alternative to `man -w` may be `man -w`.